# How to login a Drupal site from an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, drupal, authentication

Supposed there is a page which is only accessible for authenticated users on a Drupal site. What library/tools are available for iPhone developers to:

- login the Drupal site (username password)
- access the page with a loggin status

For example, I'd like to fill a UITableView with data from the Drupal page. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a way to communicate with Drupal. You can do this with the "Services module". Download it from the drupal community.

After that, on your iPhone app, you need a protocol to retrive and send data to Drupal. The most used with the Services module is XMLRPC, but you can do it with Json and even plist. In the iPhone side we're using a Cocoa XML-RPC Client Framework made by Eric J. Czarny, from Divisible by Zero.

This way you have default methods (node.get, user.login....) to retrieve info from Drupal. You can create your own modules too.

It's not complicated. We have created an app that communicates with Drupal, but its a bit extended to explain it in just a few lines.

Start by downloading the Services module, configuring it and testing with XMLRPC Server. After that, the basic work is done.

Good luck :)

Comment: You should checkout the Drupal iOS SDK, makes this much easier, https://github.com/workhabitinc/drupal-ios-sdk